# Angular Parent to Child

Tags: angular, dom, parent-child, communication

Initially My parent component doesn't have any relation with the child. Just a list of elements. but when user clicks on the list child component loads. then I am able to call a method of child component from parent using @ViewChild. But this is not working initially because there is no parent to child relation initially. how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use EventEmitter[1](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). In component you can emit any message when its loaded. And in another component you can subscribe to eventemitter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@ViewChildren` which is very much alike but also works with elements that are not yet present before the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook. Plus it wraps your elements in a [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList).

`QueryList` does have a `changes` property, which is an observable you can subscribe to. The implementation could look something like this:

```
export class SomeComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChildren(ChildComponent) children: QueryList<ChildComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.children.changes.subscribe(children => {
      children.forEach( (child: ChildComponent) => {
        child.somePublicMethod();
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used @input() to pas  the value from parent to child and used

```
ngOnChanges (changes: SimpleChanges) {
 for (let propName in changes) {
     let change = changes[propName];
     console.log(change);
 }
```

}

where ngOnChanges subscribes to change and stores the current value and previous value